# 2014 Jeep Cherokee Wiring harness ground to a 12v power outlet

Tags: wiring, cherokee, ground

can i ground tekonsha 118605 trailer harness to a 12-volt power outlet ground located in the rear cargo area on my Jeep Cherokee?i have the power wire ran to the battery and everything done except the ground and would like to keep all the wiring right ther in one area

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do, but the risk is that the ground is only large enough for the power socket capacity 5A or 10A.

I, personally, would provide a ground to a suitable earth or ground point, even the same ground point maybe that the power socket goes to...